# firebase deployment get stucks

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vx4Ao.jpg)

I am getting this error at the time of deploying the project into a firebase function.how to solve this problem.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please don't show pictures of text.  Copy the text into the question and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is usually related to the Firebase Auth Token being expired and you needing to refresh it.

For you to achieve that you can do one of the following options:

1. Run the command `firebase logout` and then run the command `firebase login`. This way, once you logout and log back in, it should generate a new token.
2. Or run `firebase login --reauth`. This should reauthenticate you and refresh the token.

Please, let me know if the information helped you!